# openvassd hanging

Tags: security

I have a problem with `openvassd` hanging while starting:

```
connect(6, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/tmp/redis.sock"}, 110) = 0
fcntl64(6, F_GETFL)                     = 0x802 (flags O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)
fcntl64(6, F_SETFL, O_RDWR)             = 0
write(6, "*3\r\n$6\r\nCONFIG\r\n$3\r\nGET\r\n$9\r\ndat"..., 40) = 40
read(6, "*2\r\n$9\r\ndatabases\r\n$2\r\n16\r\n", 16384) = 27
write(6, "*4\r\n$6\r\nHSETNX\r\n$23\r\nOpenVAS.__G"..., 60) = 60
read(6, ":0\r\n", 16384)                = 4
write(6, "*4\r\n$6\r\nHSETNX\r\n$23\r\nOpenVAS.__G"..., 60) = 60
read(6, ":0\r\n", 16384)                = 4
write(6, "*4\r\n$6\r\nHSETNX\r\n$23\r\nOpenVAS.__G"..., 60) = 60
read(6, ":0\r\n", 16384)                = 4
write(6, "*4\r\n$6\r\nHSETNX\r\n$23\r\nOpenVAS.__G"..., 60) = 60
read(6, ":0\r\n", 16384)                = 4
write(6, "*4\r\n$6\r\nHSETNX\r\n$23\r\nOpenVAS.__G"..., 60) = 60
read(6, ":0\r\n", 16384)                = 4
write(6, "*4\r\n$6\r\nHSETNX\r\n$23\r\nOpenVAS.__G"..., 60) = 60
read(6, ":0\r\n", 16384)                = 4
write(6, "*4\r\n$6\r\nHSETNX\r\n$23\r\nOpenVAS.__G"..., 60) = 60
read(6, ":0\r\n", 16384)                = 4
write(6, "*4\r\n$6\r\nHSETNX\r\n$23\r\nOpenVAS.__G"..., 60) = 60
read(6, ":0\r\n", 16384)                = 4
write(6, "*4\r\n$6\r\nHSETNX\r\n$23\r\nOpenVAS.__G"..., 60) = 60
read(6, ":0\r\n", 16384)                = 4
write(6, "*4\r\n$6\r\nHSETNX\r\n$23\r\nOpenVAS.__G"..., 61) = 61
read(6, ":0\r\n", 16384)                = 4
write(6, "*4\r\n$6\r\nHSETNX\r\n$23\r\nOpenVAS.__G"..., 61) = 61
read(6, ":0\r\n", 16384)                = 4
write(6, "*4\r\n$6\r\nHSETNX\r\n$23\r\nOpenVAS.__G"..., 61) = 61
read(6, ":0\r\n", 16384)                = 4
write(6, "*4\r\n$6\r\nHSETNX\r\n$23\r\nOpenVAS.__G"..., 61) = 61
read(6, ":0\r\n", 16384)                = 4
write(6, "*4\r\n$6\r\nHSETNX\r\n$23\r\nOpenVAS.__G"..., 61) = 61
read(6, ":0\r\n", 16384)                = 4
write(6, "*4\r\n$6\r\nHSETNX\r\n$23\r\nOpenVAS.__G"..., 61) = 61
read(6, ":0\r\n", 16384)                = 4
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
nanosleep({60, 0},
```

Seems related to `redis` but it seems OK:

```
$ redis-cli -s /tmp/redis.sock 
redis /tmp/redis.sock> monitor
OK
    1463747103.045858 [0 unix:/tmp/redis.sock] "HSETNX" "OpenVAS.__GlobalDBIndex" "1" "1"
1463747103.046033 [0 unix:/tmp/redis.sock] "HSETNX" "OpenVAS.__GlobalDBIndex" "2" "1"
1463747103.046145 [0 unix:/tmp/redis.sock] "HSETNX" "OpenVAS.__GlobalDBIndex" "3" "1"
1463747103.046244 [0 unix:/tmp/redis.sock] "HSETNX" "OpenVAS.__GlobalDBIndex" "4" "1"
1463747103.046410 [0 unix:/tmp/redis.sock] "HSETNX" "OpenVAS.__GlobalDBIndex" "5" "1"
1463747103.046528 [0 unix:/tmp/redis.sock] "HSETNX" "OpenVAS.__GlobalDBIndex" "6" "1"
1463747103.046611 [0 unix:/tmp/redis.sock] "HSETNX" "OpenVAS.__GlobalDBIndex" "7" "1"
1463747103.046703 [0 unix:/tmp/redis.sock] "HSETNX" "OpenVAS.__GlobalDBIndex" "8" "1"
1463747103.046793 [0 unix:/tmp/redis.sock] "HSETNX" "OpenVAS.__GlobalDBIndex" "9" "1"
1463747103.046887 [0 unix:/tmp/redis.sock] "HSETNX" "OpenVAS.__GlobalDBIndex" "10" "1"
1463747103.046983 [0 unix:/tmp/redis.sock] "HSETNX" "OpenVAS.__GlobalDBIndex" "11" "1"
1463747103.047084 [0 unix:/tmp/redis.sock] "HSETNX" "OpenVAS.__GlobalDBIndex" "12" "1"
1463747103.047249 [0 unix:/tmp/redis.sock] "HSETNX" "OpenVAS.__GlobalDBIndex" "13" "1"
1463747103.047344 [0 unix:/tmp/redis.sock] "HSETNX" "OpenVAS.__GlobalDBIndex" "14" "1"
```

Running `openvasmd --rebuild` did not also bring anything ...

Any idea?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, same symptoms, I even did the same strace and redis trace before I found this! Did you ever solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found some insight on [this mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/openvas-discuss@wald.intevation.org/msg11016.html).

The default redis config has 16 maximum databases. Stopping openvassd while it is in progress leaves the database locked, and starting it next time creates a new database. After 16 such unclean shutdowns, openvassd will hang on start due to lack of redis databases.

A brute-force way of fixing this is the `flushall` redis directive (substitute your redis sock file as appropriate):

```
# redis-cli -s /tmp/redis.sock 
> flushall
```

I was even able to resume my massive scan...